# como acceder al flash de un dispositivo android con api menor a 23

Tags: android

estoy programando en android y necesito acceder al flash de la camara del dispositivo. leí que la clase Camera android la considera obsoleta entonces trate de usar la clase CameraManager pero tengo un problema, en el siguiente codigo

```
public void flashOn() {

    try {
        //aca esta el problema ya que la version que estoy trabajando (api 22) es menor que la api que necesita el metodo setTorchMode (api 23)
        //entonces el if siempre es false y nunca enciende la camara
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"acceso",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mCameraManager.setTorchMode(mCameraId, true);
            rotate();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

la pregunta es ¿como hago para activar el flash en dispositivos con api menor a 23, debo usar la clase Camera que android considera obsoleta?

Comment: A ver si entendi. Quierse la camara y el flash encendido?

Comment: claro, que acceda al flash de la camara y el metodo setTorchMode encienda el flash pero ese if si trabajo con api menor a 23 siempre va a ser false

Comment: Has intentado utilizar la clase [Camera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)?

Comment: si e usado la clase Camera y si anda sin problema, el tema es que android la considera obsoleta y recomienda usar camera2, pero si no hay otra solucion usare la clase Camera

Comment: @LuchoJuniors en este caso me parece que si deseas funcione en dispositivos con API < 23 entonces la opción es usar la clase Camara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción usando la clase `Camera` ya que los método de [CameraManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html) como:

```
camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
```

requieren minimo de API 23.

---

Primeramente configurar permisos en el archivo AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

Para activar el flash se realiza de esta forma:

```
private Camera cam;

...
...
...

 if(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
    cam = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters params = cam.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    cam.setParameters(params);
    cam.startPreview();
}
```

para desactivarlo simplemente:

```
        cam.stopPreview();
        cam.release();
```

Esto puede funcionar en dispositivos con API menor a 23, justamente tengo un dispositivo con Android 5.0.1 y funciona sin problema.

Comment: si necesito que funcione en dispositivos con api menor a 23 y tambien con api mayor a 23 podria usar la clase CameraManager para dispositivos con api mayor a 23 y la clase Camera para dispositivos con api menor a 23, o uso solo Camera para todos los casos?